# Received function didn't throw in JEST

Tags: axios, jestjs, mocking

I am trying to test whether my function correctly throws an error when the API throws an error.

This is my main function

```js
export const fetchRate = async (symbol = "BTC") => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `https://rest.coinapi.io/v1/exchangerate/${symbol}/USD`,
      headers
    );
    return response;
  } catch (e) {
    throw e.response.data.error;
  }
};
```

And this is the test

```js
test("If incorrect symbol is passed the function throws an error", async () => {
  const e = {
    response: {
      data: {
        error: "We didn't find your currency",
      },
      status: 550,
    },
  };
  axios.get.mockRejectedValueOnce(e)
  await expect(fetchRate()).rejects.toThrow("We didn't find your currency");
});
```

I would expect that since I am throwing in the `catch` block this test should work, but I am constantly getting that the Received function did not throw.

Answer (score 1):

See [issue#12024](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/12024)

> `rejects.toThrow` chain expects an actual Error object to be thrown

You have thrown a `string`, not an `Error` in the `catch` block, so you need to use `.rejects.toEqual()`.

E.g.

`index.ts`:

```js
import axios from "axios";

export const fetchRate = async (symbol = 'BTC') => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`https://rest.coinapi.io/v1/exchangerate/${symbol}/USD`);
    return response;
  } catch (e) {
    throw e.response.data.error;
  }
};
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import { fetchRate } from '.';

describe('75534184', () => {
  test('If incorrect symbol is passed the function throws an error', async () => {
    const e = {
      response: {
        data: {
          error: "We didn't find your currency",
        },
        status: 550,
      },
    };
    jest.spyOn(axios, 'get').mockRejectedValueOnce(e);
    await expect(fetchRate()).rejects.toEqual("We didn't find your currency");
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/75534184/index.test.ts (8.379 s)
  75534184
    ✓ If incorrect symbol is passed the function throws an error (3 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |    87.5 |      100 |     100 |   83.33 |                   
 index.ts |    87.5 |      100 |     100 |   83.33 | 6                 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.185 s, estimated 11 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```